# Does this code have a valid declaration for the size of the array?

Tags: c, arrays

I am learning how to program arrays in C. I have a question about the following code regarding size of array. In the below code, is it a valid declaration of size of an array? Please explain me if it is either  valid or invalid.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SIZE 10

int main(void) {
  int size=12;
  float salary[size];
  salary[0]=890.54;
  printf("%f",salary[0]);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's valid size value (only with C99). You can refer from this URL for more detail:
https://www.cs.uic.edu/~jbell/CourseNotes/C_Programming/Arrays.html

Answer (score 2):

To support the other answer, if variable length arrays (VLA) are supported then yes — the declaration in the question is valid and defines a VLA. VLAs made their debut in C99 and then in C11 they are made optional. A conforming C11 compiler that does not support VLAs defines `__STDC_NO_VLA__`.

From [§6.7.6.2¶4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.2p4)

> If the size is not present, the array type is an incomplete type. If the size is `*` instead of being an expression, the array type is a variable length array type of unspecified size, which can only be used in declarations or type names with function prototype scope;<sup>143)</sup> such arrays are nonetheless complete types. *If the size is an integer constant expression and the element type has a known constant size, the array type is not a variable length array type; otherwise, the array type is a variable length array type.* (Variable length arrays are a conditional feature that implementations need not support; see 6.10.8.3.)

from [§6.10.8.3¶1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.8.3)

> `__STDC_NO_VLA__`
>   The integer constant 1, intended to indicate that the implementation does not support variable length arrays or variably modified types